# Добавить новый элемент по клику

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="my_class"></div>
<button class="add">Добавить</button>

    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
// Код...
    });
```

Как при нажатии на кнопку создать в div новый input ?

```
 <div class="my_class"><input type="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        let elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.className = "form";
        var Elem1 = document.getElementsByClassName('my_class');
        elem.append(Elem1[0]);
        document.body.prepend(elem);
        console.log(elem);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_class"></div>
<button class="add">Добавить</button>
```